# Rails Thin server unresponsive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine, thin

I have installed Ruby 1.9.2-p290 (via RVM) and Rails 3.2.2. EventMachine 0.12.10, Thin 1.3.1 and Rack 1.4.0

Im starting the application like this:

```
zonic@laptop:~/rails-projects/project$ bundle exec thin start --threaded
>> Using rack adapter
/home/zonic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PNG
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

And there it remains, forever. I try to navigate to localhost:3000 but it just doesn't reply. When i crtl+c it, this is what i get:

```
^C>> Stopping ...
log writing failed. deadlock; recursive locking
```

I've searched for this problem in the web but with no luck. My current OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting thin in threaded mode. Did you uncomment config.threadsafe! in your rails config so that it plays well with a threaded server?

Comment: Yes i've just checked that and its uncommented. Still trying to find a clue. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that threaded version of thin does not work with some versions of ruby and you have to use the --no-epoll option to get it working. Perhaps you should try that.